# How many child tables can participate on one parent table?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I used inheritance feature from Postgresql 9.6 to create some archive for huge amount of data.

Finally parent table looks like this

```
foo=# \d+ foo_data_sshcommand 
                                                        Table "public.foo_data_sshcommand"
   Column   |           Type           |                             Modifiers                             | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                  | not null default nextval('foo_data_sshcommand_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 time       | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                          | plain    |              | 
 command    | text                     | not null                                                          | extended |              | 
 success    | boolean                  | not null                                                          | plain    |              | 
 session_id | integer                  | not null                                                          | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "foo_data_sshcommand_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "foo_data_sshcommand_session_id_c8b38d68" btree (session_id)
Check constraints:
    "partition_check" CHECK ("time" >= '2019-10-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone) NO INHERIT
Foreign-key constraints:
    "foo_data_sshcommand_session_id_c8b38d68_fk" FOREIGN KEY (session_id) REFERENCES foo_data_sshsession(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Child tables: arc_2019_01_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_02_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_03_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_04_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_05_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_06_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_07_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_08_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_09_foo_data_sshcommand,
              arc_2019_foo_data_sshcommand
```

Every month it creates two more tables and it adds them to the archive. It is not nice process, because it must move overflowed data from parent table to new child table. But it is not the problem that I want to talk about. I am curious about question - How many tables can paricipate on inheritance of one parent table?

Comment: I tried to google it and nothing found...

Comment: In theory unlimited. In reality a couple of thousands is usually too much. But if you do need partitioning, you should **really** consider upgrading to v11 or v12 as they have massive improvements in that area

Comment: Could you add a link to some official documentation or as I presume it is your experience?

Comment: For 9.6 the limit is very low [as stated in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CAVEATS): "*so large numbers of partitions are likely to increase query planning time considerably. Partitioning using these techniques will work well with up to perhaps **a hundred partitions**; don't try to use many thousands of partitions*"

Comment: In the corresponding [chapter in v12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-BEST-PRACTICES)  it states: "*The query planner is generally able to handle partition hierarchies with up to a few thousand partitions fairly well*"

Comment: I cannot mark your answer as the right one because of being in comments. So, thank you, it helps a lot to enable me to create a picture how long the archive solution keeps healthy.